# Is this vector question simpler than I think it is?

Tags: vectors

If **a** $= (2,-6,3)^T$ and **b** $= (-5,4,3)^T$, what is **b** written in $i,j,k$ component form?

I feel like $b = -5i+4j+3k$ is too simple for a $3$ mark question - is there a conversion I've missed?

Comment: That is correct. It does seem like a relatively simple problem, but unless you've misread it your answer is right.

Comment: Seems to be right, unless in your problem you are working with diferent basis.